# Restrict SystemDialogInput to open certain file types

Tags: files-and-directories, dialog-window

The documentation for `SystemDialogInput` shows how to restrict the types of files shown.

```
SystemDialogInput["FileOpen",".nb"]
```

...only shows *Mathematica* notebook files. This also works for other file extensions such as ".txt", ".html", etc., but doesn't work for other file types.

If I have a tab delimited file that with extension ".data" and try:

```
SystemDialogInput["FileOpen",".data"]
```

...the dialog box defaults to all files.

Is there a way to only show other "non-standard" file types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SystemDialogInput["FileOpen", {"Data", {"Data" -> {"*.data", "*.dat"}}}]
```

The [doc page for `SystemDialogInput`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SystemDialogInput.html) describes under "More Information" how to create new file types by listing the patterns they match.

Comment: Crap, just figured it out. What purpose does the *init* argument have in this case?

Comment: @kale You can define several allowed file types.  `init` gives the one the dialog is set to when launched.